# Is it possible to send wifi info to a device in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am completely new to react-native and try to learn it to build an app for the company I work for.

We have devices that need to be configured before they can be used and we want to build an app to do so. We tough we could use react-native.

The configuration that need to be done on the device is to tell it which wifi network it need to connect to. Initially, the device have it's own wifi network. We need to connect to it and then we send the new network info so it can be connected to the local wifi.

The problem I am facing is that I can't find anywhere how to send wifi information to an external device.

Comment: "Initially, the device have it's own wifi network" -> This is wifi hotspot of device, right?

Comment: Even for a native iOS app you won't be able to get list of available network  SSIDs inside your application. But you may do it for Android. For iOS case you will need connect your iOS device initially to theWiFi Access point provided by your custom device via Phone Settings (see WiFi setting). You need to know IP address of your device and after it you may connect to your device and do what you want. For Android you may scan available SSIDs directly from your app.

Comment: Yes, I mean hotspot.

Once I am connected to the hotspot, is there a standard way to communicate with the device?

 Sorry if my questions seem weird, but I know nothing about the subject.  And I don't know where to start searching.

Comment: Did you figure out how to accomplish this?

Comment: @Dmitry A. Once I know ip address to device and are on the same wifi hotspot how do I access the device?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a QR code to encode the SSID, and read it with a QR code reader: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera

And then use react-native-wifi to connect to the network: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi

If you're using Expo however, you will need to detach first: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/detach